# MySQL - Group and return single row for each group based on most recent

Tags: mysql

So I'm having an issue with what I expect is a very simple problem, but for the life of me I can't figure it out!

I have a table like this:

```
id    name      status     date
1      bob       good      01/01/2020
2      john      good      01/01/2020
3      bob       bad       02/01/2020
4      john      good      02/01/2020
5      ben       good      02/01/2020
```

I want to retrieve the latest record for each name.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT name
    ,STATUS
    ,MAX(DATE)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX(DATE)
```

I thought this worked, however it is returning a record for bob, john and ben, but it is showing bobs date as 02/01/2020 but his status as "good" from the other record!

At a loss as to how to do this in the simplest way possible, all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Maria DB 10.2 apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of this as aggregation.  Think of this as filtering!

```
Select t.name, t.status, t.date
from table t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from table t2
                where t2.name = t.name
               );
```

You are not *aggregating* anything.  Your result set just wants columns from one row, the row with the maximum date for each name.  That is more like filtering than grouping.

Answer (score 0):

With `not exists`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and date > t.date
)
```

The result is: 
every row of the table for which there is not another row with the same `name` and later `date`.
For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.status, t.date
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I went with the other answer but this also looks good, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Maria DB 10.2 apparently. – Ed Jones

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, 
                FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name 
                                          ORDER BY date DESC) status,
                MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY name) date
FROM table;
```

The index by `(name, data)` will increase the performance.